# ¿Por qué tengo este error en la base de datos en xampp?

Tags: base-de-datos, xampp, drupal, drupal7

Tengo un error en la base de datos, esto es lo que me dice:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'gradbook.gbook_semaphore' doesn't exist: SELECT expire, value
>   FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init
>   ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\librodelgraduado\includes\lock.inc).

pero cuando le paso la basa de datos, empieza a leerla, se para, sigue leyendo y después da error. Estoy usando Drupal 7 y MySQL.

Comment: estas usando php o algún framework?

Comment: Estoy usando drupal 7 y mysql

Comment: ¿Podrìas detallar mejor tu problema? Sería genial también si incluyes parte del código que estas usando y expliques la lógica detrás de ello